# Compare two XML - Java Elements with Reflection

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, reflection

I have Two large XML files and i have Java classes for every xml atribute.

What i do now:

- unmarshal XML Files with JAXB.
- I finaly have Two classes which i can use to get the whole file (all classes/ tags)

How the structure of the classes are:

For example with this xml file.

```
<GRANDFATHER ID="1" NAME="Hallo">
  <\FATHER>
    <SON>
    <\SON>
  <\FATHER>
</GRANDFATHER >
```

after unmarhaling i would have an object -> GRANDFATHER
with this object i could make GRANDFATHER.getFATHER
and then from FATHER .getSON i now need to compare each object with the other by ID
couse there are so many classes this would be a huge ammount of hardcoding
so i thaught about houw i could do this by Reflection. Tried but could not find a way.
Any Ideas ? If you have a system or algorithm in mind i would highly apreciate it Thanks.

Comment: Google for "java compare java beans" to find a number of ways.

Comment: In case you do not want a list of different attributes/properties , and just to check if 2 xml files are equal or not, why don't you override `equals` for each class in order to have these classes compared by ids? Or use custom comparators if you want to achieve the same goal.

Comment: JaxB is not really a solution. It would be better to use a Sax parser and directly match the content. Else you will have to create yourself an object to recurse on istelf through each element and check it against the second jaxb object. Mostly i would sugest using xml path to do the validations for you.

Comment: @Daniel i need to write the results in a .csv

Comment: @WarGodNT What exactly do you mean by results?  Could you provide a specific example of input and output for your problem?

Comment: @Daniel here -> is my problem a bit beter explained i guess http://xtream.ch/chalange-xml-compare-algorithm-extras-win-price/
however csv output should look like this GRANDFATHERID;FATHERID;SONID;OLDVALUE;NEWVALUE if the differece is on FATHER Level SONID can be Null in the Output file

Comment: @KennethClark  thank you for the input could you make an example ? would highly appreciate it.

Comment: There is quite a good explanation of using xpaths on the foloowing link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895262/parse-xml-file-using-xpath-expressions-and-java

are you looking for the xpath example ?

Comment: Ran across this earlier. it may assist you with most of your troubles http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/xml-comparison-tutorial-using-xmlunit/